# How can I cast const unsigned char * to uint8 *

Tags: c++

I am using a API function where data should be passed as (uint8 *) type.
But I am getting data of type (const unsigned char *) form.
Here is my sample implementation:

```
virtual int
  read_data (uint32 addr, unsigned char *buf, size_t *nbytes)
    {
        MemRead (addr, buf, nbytes);
        return 0;
    }
```

getting following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 
                                          'uint8* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
```

so, how can I manage cast from const unsigned char* to uint8 *.

Comment: what is `MemRead()`?

Comment: "how can I manage cast from const unsigned char* to uint8 *" - just write a cast...

Comment: Is this a misspelling?  My understanding is that the type is `uint8_t`, note the *_t* suffix.  Also, did you include the correct header file?

Comment: Are you sure, overwriting data which is const ?

Comment: Do you understand the point of `const`? You have a `const unsigned char *`/`const uint8_t *`/`const uint8 *` (however you spell it) that points to some data that you promised you wouldn't modify. You then attempt to modify it. Of *course* the compiler is going to complain. Re-think your design.

Comment: You must post the calling code, because you seem to have something wrong in it, why would you pass a `const unsigned char *` to a function named `read_data`? Please post the caller function.

Comment: @iharob , read_data function is just a virtual function that I am extending in my class and cannot be change its arguments.

Comment: Then what is it's purpose?

Comment: Why is `buf` const? As others have mentioned, it's both nonsense and dangerous to cast away constness, unless you have a very good reason for a hack like this and know exactly what you're doing (i.e., you wouldn't be asking this question). Either your API is broken or you're using it wrong.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Simply prepend `(uint8*)` to your `buf` argument:

`MemRead (addr, (uint8*)buf, nbytes);`

**EDIT:**

I overlooked that the `buf` pointer is not declared as `const`. The cast at this point is unnecessary as stated in some comments. However casting can be done by prepending `(uint8*)`. If this is good practice is another question.

Comment: What a bad idea is that... And besides you are casting nothing and also in c++ it is `reinterpret_cast<uint8 *>(buf)`.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: @iharob `(uint8*)buf` is still valid in C++. But you're right that it's a horrible idea. I put a comment on the question to explain why.

Comment: @user0815 Because `const` is there to protect data, so you should not arbitrarily cast constness away, or else way would the variable be `const` qualified? And also, this answer is wrong because the problems is casting from `const unsigned char *` to `unsigned char *` so this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Because C-style casts are frowned upon in C++. C++ introduced `reinterpret_cast<>`, `dynamic_cast<>`, `static_cast<>` and `const_cast<>` in order to explicitate exactly the type of cast required..

Comment: @iharob That comment seems to be addressed to user0815, not to me. I'm the one who agreed that it's a bad idea, user0815 is the one who asked why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @hvd oh, sorry it's a little dark here and i got confused...

Comment: The different cast types only matter for class types.

Comment: this code works properly for me

Comment: `The different cast types only matter for class types` ... uh, what?

Comment: I only answered the question the OP was asking without evaluating his purpose. Maybe there are good reasons to do it that way.

Comment: @user0815 No you didn't, the cast is absolutely unnecessary, because both types are the same, check the `aka ... ` part...

Comment: I am wondering, how people just voting without any reason.

Comment: @EquationSolver If this answer works for you, then you didn't post the actual code you're having trouble with in your question. Based on what you asked, this answer is completely and utterly useless, and the answerer just got lucky that your question was just as bad. At any rate, even then, even if it compiles, this answer is *still* a horrible idea as already pointed out.

Comment: @EquationSolver besides, works doesn't neessarily mean works, undefined behavior can do nothing sometimes, until the right conditions are met and then you will see the most unexpected behavior you can think of...

Comment: @EquationSolver "I am wondering, how people just voting without any reason" Simple, there is a reason, you just do not see it. C cast is bad, because leads to very difficult to catch runtime problems. I bet your next question here will be "why my program suddenly crash?"

Comment: @EquationSolver I sure hope you're not going to be using this program for anything important.